# Selecting all tracks in iTunes with AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes, rating

I have this very basic AppleScript which I'm trying to run on my Mac to remove the ratings from all my songs in iTunes:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set sel to every track in library playlist
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of sel
        set rating of track i in sel to 0
    end repeat
end tell
```

I've never written anything in AppleScript before, but thought I'd give it a shot (since it's supposed to be so intuitive). Unfortunately, I receive this error when  I try to run the script:

```
error "Can’t get every track of library playlist." number -1728 
from every «class cTrk» of «class cLiP»
```

What is this error? Is there an alternate way of selecting the tracks in iTunes? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't entirely know why, but the answer is that the library playlist doesn't actually contain tracks.  Strange, I know, but since you just want to run this over every track, there's an even simpler solution. Rather than `every track of library`, just use `every track`; this will get literally every track in the application, which is what you're trying to do.  And with a few other simplifications, this becomes

```
tell application "iTunes" to set the rating of every track to 0
```

The `tell application "iTunes" to ...` syntax is just like an ordinary `tell` block, but it's only one statement long and doesn't take an `end tell`.  And you can automatically run the `set` command over every entry in the list at once, so that's all you need.  In general, you rarely need to enumerate via indices; for instance, for something closer to your solution, there's the equivalent

```
tell application "iTunes"
  repeat with t in every track
    set the rating of t to 0
  end repeat
end tell
```

This avoids the indexing, and will also likely be faster (though the one-liner will probably be fastest, *if* there's a difference).

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer and explanation. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You've been misinformed: AppleScript is not very intuitive, primarily because so much of its observed behavior is determined by each application's implementation of its object model.  While it can be very powerful, you often just have to experiment until you find the right incantations that work for a particular application.

In this case, you need to select the first item of playlists.  Note the differences:

```
get library playlist
    Result:
        library playlist  -- the class
get library playlists
    Result:
        {library playlist id 51776 of source id 67 of application "iTunes"} -- a list
get first library playlist
    Result:
        library playlist id 51776 of source id 67 of application "iTunes" -- first item
```

But what you probably want to do is something more like this:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with tr in every track in first Library playlist
        set rating of tr to 60  -- values are 0 to 100
    end repeat
end tell
```

If you have a large library, you might want to first experiment with a smaller playlist, for instance, select a track in a test playlist and then substitute `in current playlist` in the `repeat` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the different results returned by the script. I've accepted the other answer only because it's the most concise and fastest in my tests. Cheers!

Comment: What I've found is that AppleScript often feels like a "read-only" language—whatever ends up working is generally readable, but getting there can be tough without experience.

Comment: I see two major issues: 1. the inconsistent and unpredictable behavior of the various applications' Apple Events and object model interface; and 2. the quirks of the AppleScript language itself.  There's not much that a user can do about the former (although the built-in scripting capabilites that Cocoa provides has helped somewhat to give a more consistent experience across apps).  My preferred solution to the latter is to avoid writing programs in AppleScript but instead use py-appscript which gives the benefit of a richer language and library, python (there's also rb-appscript for Ruby).